# How to remove the space between rows of grid view in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

In android grid view there is extra space between the rows of grid view. I am not adding any space to the gridview.

here is my xml files

```
        <GridView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5px"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:columnWidth="50dip"
                 android:verticalSpacing="0dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
```

and the other xml for the imageview which is adding view to the gridview is

```
        <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/singlePhoto"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="145dip"
            android:layout_height="145dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            >
        </ImageView>
```

In Adapter class the code is

```
        if(mView == null){
            mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.newsgridthumbpic, null);
                }

                ImageView mImage = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.singlePhoto);
                PhotoGridInfoSet mInfo = (PhotoGridInfoSet)details.get(position);
                if(mImage != null){
                mImage.setTag(mInfo.getPhotoThumbNailString());
                mImage.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                mImage.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
                }
        }!
```

The space is between the rows of gridview. I have not added any space anywhere in the code Still the there is vertical spacing.I am not able understand why there is space in between gridview rows. This space is not appearing in the hdpi device/emulator. This problem is in the mdpi and ldpi devices/emulator.

[image: Image for reference. this is what happening right now.]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem.

To solve this i need to add 1 line in my xml file

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

and after adding this. the space is not appearing now

Comment: did you add this to the grivview or the grid item? It doesn't appear to work for me :(

Comment: Add this to imageview, Works for me... Thanx Dipali

Comment: IMPORTANT: like Anchit mentioned, this should be placed in imageview.

Comment: Hi, Dipali it is not working for me ... can you please tell me how to resolve this issue ?? in my case i have 2 columns and i don't want any space between images ...

Comment: but where in xml file ? in GridView  or any where else ??

Comment: Great, spent a few hours on finding this. Could be that the view inside gridview needs to be redrawn after placing an image.

Comment: both      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);   and imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true); worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just put last 2 lines in gridView

```
<GridView
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in ur getView() method...

```
mImage.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your picture is being scaled to fit the column width of 50dp while maintaining the aspect ratio. This is introducing a bunch of unfilled space in the vertical layout. If you want your column to be 50dp wide, the easiest way to work out these spacing issues will be to adjust your imageview to have a width of 50dp and adjust the imageviews height proportional to that.

Comment: Even if i change it to dip it is showing the space between rows and the prob is about vertical spacing

Comment: The height of the views you are placing in the grid define the grids height. that mixed with your gravity being set to "top" is what is causing your grid to look like that.

Answer (score 0):

just check that your **"newsgridthumbpic"** layout does not contain the extra padding or any background image having a large height that your grid view element.
Also double check that you are supplying **column_width** as **50dip** but your **"imageview's"** width is **145 dip**.

Comment: yea i have tried all that things changing the imageview height n width

and the images are coming from server thats why there is no background or src images

Answer (score 0):

Setting  android:verticalSpacing in the gridview to negative values.
will remove the vertical space.

(Eg:  android:verticalSpacing="-10dp")

test with some number to get the right value

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5px"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:columnWidth="50dip"
     android:verticalSpacing="0dip"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singlePhoto"
    android:layout_width="145dip"
    android:layout_height="145dip"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation, and not code only.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY"   is the attribute that helps in fixing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have another way as a fixing for the same issue while one using **RecyclerView**.

Just pass the number of **SpanCount** like I have given 6 in **GridLayoutManager(this, 6)** and change the SpanCount to reduce or increase the gap between the items in the RecyclerView.

Check this sample code-

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6);
  rvSizes.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
  SizeSelectorAdaptersizeChooserAdapter = new SizeSelectorAdapter(this, sizes);
  rvSizes.setAdapter(sizeChooserAdapter);
```

Hope this will be useful.
Thank you