# Can't remove padding ImageView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, padding

Here is a gridview:
[test_grid.xml]

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http:....."
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<GridView
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:numColumns="6"

    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"

android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
>
  </GridView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

and an imageview:
image_item.xml

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http:....."
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageLetter"

    android:padding="0dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And in GridAdapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
    }

  ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageLetter);

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return imageView;
```

Problem is: couldn't remove padding around imageview, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dPu2.png)
I tried this:

```
  imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

but no results. Appreciate any help, advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705330/gridview-and-excess-space-padding/9106404#9106404

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125014/how-to-remove-the-space-between-rows-of-grid-view-in-android/9142456#9142456

Comment: Try using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your ImageView

Comment: not working, still having spaces between

Comment: if in griedview replace match_parent to wrap_content?

Comment: unfortunately not working(

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your **ImageView** layout. Give width and height `wrap_content` instead of **`xxdp`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http:....."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageLetter"
        android:padding="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My it will work for you.

Comment: thx for reply. After changing image layout width to wrap_content it becomes bigger in size and shows only 3 columns of GridView

Comment: because `streachMode="columnWidth"`, Remove it. May Help

Comment: removed, but still the same. Should I resize my original .png image(make it smaller)??

Comment: Can you please post Screenshots.

Comment: and with this parameters:  <GridView xmlns=...."  android:id="@+id/grid_view"  android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent"      
    android:padding="0dp"       
    android:numColumns="6"       

          
    <ImageView xmlns:android="....."  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="0dp" />